# how to use shell scrip with snmpwalk with OID to have vlan ID , vlan name , port belong to vlans in Excel table

Tags: linux, shell-script, network-interface

right now i m using this command

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public IP@ 1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.1.3.2.6.1.1
```